# Visual Studio C++ Error: Expected an Identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, game-engine, sdl-2

I have been receiving errors saying that the compiler expected an identifier. Can someone help me and let me know what it means? Here are all of my files and the errors I am getting are line 6, 61, 62 in Game, line 5 in main, and line 12 in Game Header.

[Game header](https://pastebin.com/aLg1dxUw)

[Game](https://pastebin.com/rRRHvMhd)

[main](https://pastebin.com/KUn1Ugrw)

Game

```
#ifndef Game.h
#define Game.cpp


#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();

    bool running() { return isRunning; }

private:
    bool isRunning;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Whats `#ifndef Game.h` and `#define Game.cpp`?

Comment: Please add the error here.

Comment: Please read about [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). You can't use `.` in macro name (just like in any identifier name in C), and name in both `ifndef` and `define` must be the same for it to function as include guard. Also your `#undef main` makes no sense in `game.cpp`, and I would recommend against it even in `main.cpp`.